# How to return from the yylex()?

Tags: lex

I am writing lex code to convert tabs into spacebars (one tab equals 4 spacebars) and count those spacebars. The code is as following:

```
%{
 #include<stdio.h>
 int spacebarCount=0;
%}

%%
[\t]    {
        spacebarCount+=4;
        }
[ ]     {
        spacebarCount++;
        }
%%

int main()
    {
    yylex();
    printf("The spacebar is: %d",spacebarCount);
    spacebarCount=0;
    }
```

The output should print a statement: printf("The spacebar is: %d",spacebarCount); However it didn't. So what should I do to make it print the output I wanted? Also, I have tried to substitute the statements below in the main function but it didn't work.

```
 int main()
    {
    do
       {
       if(yylex()==0);
          {
          printf("The spacebar is: %d",spacebarCount);
          spacebarCount=0; 
          }
       }while(1);
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify: when would you want the count printed? At the end of a file, end of a line, or at some other point?

Comment: I want the count printed at the end of a line.

Comment: And in addition, I use Lex not Flex.

Answer (score 0):

In flex this can be handled by matching the End-Of-File with the pattern `<<EOF>>`:

```
%{
 #include<stdio.h>
 int spacebarCount=0;
%}

%%
[\t]    {
        spacebarCount+=4;
        }
[ ]     {
        spacebarCount++;
        }
<<EOF>> {
        printf("The spacebar is: %d",spacebarCount);
        return 0;
        }
%%

int main()
    {
    yylex();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Brian Tompsett. If my input is standard input (Get input from keyboard) Does <<EOF>> rule match when I tab (or spacebar) in the command line?

Comment: @brian: op might be expecting an output on every line. There is no need for the explicit EOF rule here, since yylex will just return 0 on EOF by default. If you use an explicit EOF rule, you *must* return from its action; otherwise you have UB. (You must also avoid reentering yylex afterwards.)